# Configure Qt library 4.8.1 error when I cross compile

Tags: qt, configuration, arm

I’m compiling the Qt with phonon and phonon-backend for my embedded board.
I type:

```
./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -qt-mouse-tslib -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/lib -L/home/user/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/lib -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -prefix /opt/qt_eng -little-endian -no-gif -no-libtiff -no-libmng -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-largefile -no-sm -svg -v -no-feature-cursor -fast -opensource -release -no-multimedia -no-cups -no-nis  -no-exceptions -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-sql-sqlite -no-g++-exceptions -phonon -phonon-backend -DQT_NO_QWS_CURSOR -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT
```

with qmake.conf in /home/user/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++:

```
#
# qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-g++ #


include(../../common/gcc-base.conf)
include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../../common/g++.conf)
include(../../common/linux.conf)
include(../../common/qws.conf)

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE     = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8
-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp

DEFINES +=

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = sb2 -t imx53 gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = sb2 -t imx53 g++
QMAKE_LINK              = sb2 -t imx53 g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = sb2 -t imx53 g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = sb2 -t imx53 ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = sb2 -t imx53 objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP             = sb2 -t imx53 strip

load(qt_config)
```

If I remove `-phonon -phonon-backend` from option the compilation is successful.
If I put `-phonon -phonon-backend`
I have this error:

```
.
.
.
D-Bus auto-detection... ()
Project WARNING: Your mkspec is including 'common/g++.conf', but the mkspecs have been refactored
 To fix this include 'common/gcc-base-.conf and 'common/g++-.conf' instead
sb2 -t imx53 g++ -c -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -o dbus.o dbus.cpp
dbus.cpp:43:23: error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
dbus.cpp:46:2: error: #error Needs at least dbus version 1
dbus.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
dbus.cpp:51: error: 'dbus_shutdown' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [dbus.o] Error 1
D-Bus disabled.
Glib auto-detection... ()
Project WARNING: Your mkspec is including 'common/g++.conf', but the mkspecs have been refactored
To fix this include 'common/gcc-base-.conf and 'common/g++-.conf' instead
sb2 -t imx53 g++ -c -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -pipe -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -O2 -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include -I/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -o glib.o glib.cpp
glib.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
glib.cpp:55: warning: 'pollfd' is used uninitialized in this function
sb2 -t imx53 g++ -Wl,-O1 -o glib glib.o     -L/home/user/ev-sdk/rootfs/arm-a8-fs/usr/lib -L/home/user/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/lib
*glib.o: In function `main':
glib.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `g_thread_init'
glib.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `g_main_context_default'
glib.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `g_source_new'
glib.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `g_source_add_poll'
glib.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `g_threads_got_initialized'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [glib] Error 1*
Glib disabled.
Phonon support cannot be enabled due to functionality tests!
 Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to ./configure to see the final report.
 If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue
 switch (-continue) to ./configure to continue.
```

I lost the last two days to understand why giving error.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Didn't you already investigate those undefined references? Do you have libgthread-2.0 in your sysroot?

Answer (score 1):

Debian/linux can use:

```
   $ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

The command can be run before run `./configure`

Answer (score 0):

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR           += -L$${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/lib
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += -I$${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/include/glib-2.0
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += -I$${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
QMAKE_LIBS             += -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -v
```